# Javascript Blob to File / Sending Files through Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

In an Express app, I have a simple image uploader which was working perfectly using Ajax PUT requests. But now I need to crop the images before sending them to the server.

I plugged in [Croppie](http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) to help with this. On form submit I get the cropped image blobs from Croppie, convert them to files, append the files to the Ajax FormData object, and send the FormData off to Express.

But the server isn't receiving and files, and examining the PUT request in Chrome's dev tools shows that no file info is being send.

I've console.logged the blobs and the files, and as far as I can tell they are being created properly.

Getting the blobs and converting them to files:

```
var fileList = []
if($croppieContainers.length > 0){
  $.each($croppieContainers, function(i){
    $(this).croppie('result', {
      type: 'blob',                       // Get the blob from the croppie container
    }).then(function(blob) {
      let file = new File([blob], "image-" + i, {
        type: blob.type,                    
        lastModifiedDate: new Date();     //  Make a file from the blob...
      });
      fileList.push(file)                 // And push it to fileList
    });
  });
}
```

Appending the files to ajaxData:

```
if(fileList.length > 0) {
  $.each('fileList', function(file){
    ajaxData.append($input.attr('name'), file);
  })
}
```

posting to Express:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $form.attr('action'),
  type: $form.attr('method'),
  data: ajaxData,
  // dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  complete: function() {
    $form.removeClass('is-uploading');
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // Handlers...
```

Console.log(blob) returns:

```
Blob
  size:288345
  type: "image/png"
  __proto__: Blob
```

And the file:

```
File
  lastModified : 1478972364233
  lastModifiedDate : Sat Nov 12 2016 17:39:24 GMT+0000 (GMT)
  name : "image-0"
  size : 288345
  type : "image/png"
  webkitRelativePath : ""
  __proto__ : File
```

I've tried getting the file a different way, but it gives the same result:

```
  if($croppieContainers.length > 0){
    $.each($croppieContainers, function(i){
      let file = new File([$(this).croppie('result', {
        type: 'blob'}
      )],
      "image-" + i)
      ajaxData.append($input.attr('name'),file)
    });
  }
```

I'm note sure how to debug this, apart from console.logging at various stages, and checking the XHR in dev tools...

Can anyone see what the problem is, or tell me how I can debug further?

Thanks you!